# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/

Tags: debian, mysql, php

I am working with php(7.3) and mysql in linux machine. But I am getting PHP `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/` error in apache2 log file (`/var/log/error.log`). I checked few  answers [Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found). But did't work.

### form-handler.php

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Users");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
    echo "Connected successfully";
$username = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"]; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = " . $username . " AND password =" . $password; 
$re = mysqli_query($query); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($re) == 0) 
    { echo 'Not Logged In'; } 
else 
    { echo 'Logged In'; }
?>
```

### Edit 1

Already done executing the following commands

`apt install php-mysql`
`apt-get install php-mysqlnd`

### Edit 2

I created new php file with the following code

```
<?php
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
?>
```

and in **additional modules it doesn't show mysqli** but when I execute `apt install php-mysql` it shows php-mysql is already the **newest version** (2:7.3+69)..

Comment: By "didn't work" means that you tried to install the mysql library? Does it apperar on `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yeah PHP is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told us which OS you are using. But since you've already mentioned `apt-get` then I'll assume that you're using something similar to Ubuntu or Debian.  These have a relatively similar configuration setup.

**Check 1**

The package `php-mysql` should be dependent on `php7.2-mysql` or similar so firstly check that this is installed eg:

```bsh
dpkg --list | grep 'php.*mysql'
ii  php-mysql                        2:7.2+69ubuntu1                   all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.2-mysql                     7.2.19-0ubuntu0.19.04.1           amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Do take a note of which version you have installed, if not 7.2 like my setup you will need to change later checks to match your version.

**Check 2**

I've just looked at my Ubuntu 19.04 setup and mysqli has it's own shared library currently installed to belonging to the `php7.2-mysql` package and installed to `/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so`.

```
find /usr/lib/php -name mysqli.so
```

**Check 3**

For PHP to use the module, it needs to be instructed to load it.  Depending on the way you have setup PHP to run you may need to look in a different place.  But for me, running PHP 7.2 under phpfpm, the instruction to load mysqli is located in: `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini`.

Check to see if you have the module loaded with:

```
grep mysqli.so /etc/php/7.2/*/conf.d/*
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini:extension=mysqli.so
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini:extension=mysqli.so
```

Make sure that whichever way you are using PHP` is configured to load the module. 
 If it is not configured to do so then you should be able to add back the configuration:

```
cd /etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d
ln -s ../../mods-available/mysqli.ini 20-mysqli.ini
```

**Check 3 is the most likly to be the cause given the evidence you've shown, but it's also the mos easy to make a mistake on.**

Comment: I'd like to add to this: in the php.ini (or the .ini you're using), the mysqlnd extension needs to be specified before mysqli, because of its dependency upon mysqlnd.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your php installation lacks mysql module. You can check if its installed with `php -i` in your shell. If you don't, try to install it.

For Ubuntu:

```
apt install php-mysql
```

For CentOS:

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Comment: Already done. But not working.

Comment: Not working means that you got an error, or the package is installed OK?

Comment: As the title, I am getting "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/" in apache2 log file. Therefore MySQL query is not executing.

Comment: @PushpamKumar Please restrain from using the phrase _not working_ when explaining your issue. Its not informative at all. Do you have the php-mysql installed? Is it listed in the php info?

Comment: Ohkay I will take care of it.
yes `php-mysql` is installed

Comment: @PushpamKumar We understood what your error says, wich may mean the package mysql is not installed, but you just answer this just now.

Comment: When I run `php form-handler.php` it doesnot give any error related to mysqli. @guillermochamorro @deimos

Answer (score 0):

**Confirm that your MySQL version should compatible with PHP version**

*Detail*:-

First, ensure that in phpinfo page you should have mysqli installed information if not then.....
[image]

, install it and if you think you already installed it in your pc but not working

then Confirm that your MySQL version should compatible with PHP version
like

first I was using this pair for MySQL and PHP

- php:7.4-apache & mysql:5.7 (but it was not working and showing error
  Class 'mysqli' not found)

after that I installed

- **php:7.2-apache & mysql:5.7** and **it works fine for me**